# trouble with LIKE query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Here are tables similar to the structure I have:

```
person table 
id    first_name    last_name
```

```
fruits table 
id   name
```

```
person_fruits table
id    person_id    fruits_id
```

A person can have multiple fruits and drinks.

When I do
`SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name LIKE '%key%' OR last_name LIKE '%key%'`, I get the correct results

But I need to match the fruits or drinks too. When I do the below query, I get incomplete results:

```
 SELECT * FROM person WHERE 
     first_name LIKE '%key%' 
     OR last_name LIKE '%key%'
     OR (
         SELECT DISTINCT(person.id) 
             FROM fruits, person_fruits 
             WHERE 
               person.id = person_fruits.person_id 
               AND person_fruits.fruits_id = fruits.id 
               AND fruits.name LIKE '%$key%'
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

try a left join, see if this works for you

```
SELECT * FROM person_fruits LEFT JOIN person ON person.id=person_fruits.person_id LEFT JOIN fruits ON fruits.id=person_fruits.fruits_id WHERE first_name LIKE '%key%' 
 OR last_name LIKE '%key%'
```

Comment: Can it work inside of the `OR ()`?
I tried your reformatted query and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

#### Row for each variation

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, f.name
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person_fruits pf on p.id=pf.person_id
LEFT JOIN fruits f on f.id=pf.fruits_id
WHERE p.first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?
```

This will list all persons, whether they have fruits or not, and will give a row per person per fruit.

#### Aggregated results

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, group_concat(f.name) fruits
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person_fruits pf on p.id=pf.person_id
LEFT JOIN fruits f on f.id=pf.fruits_id
WHERE p.first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?
GROUP BY p.id
```

This will give one row per person, with fruits listed as csv.

Comment: I needed it to match the fruits.name too, not have a list of the fruits for the matched first_name and last_name

Comment: Oh, well then add that into the `where` clause. If you want only results of names that have fruits / drinks (???) then change the left joins to inner joins. I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish

Comment: thank you for this comment. this gave me the idea of how to construct the correct query, which I have!

Comment: Glad to help :)